# Why does db:seed return Class app/Product doesnt exist?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to seed my database but cmd just returns this FatalThrowableError that "Class app\Product is not found"

This is my migrations file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['imagepath','title','description','price'];
}
```

Here is my Providers file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['imagepath','title','description','price'];
}
```

And here is my Seeder file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ProductTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $product=new \app\Product([
            'imagepath' =>'https://cdn.djcity.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/14082413/launchkey-mini-elevated_0.jpg',
            'title' =>'Novation LaunchKey Mini mk2 MIDI',
            'description' =>'issa book',
            'price' =>'125'
        ]);
        $product ->save();
```

cmd just returns that `$product=new \app\Product`  Class is not found

This is my migrations file for my SQLSTATE [42S22] Problem when I try to seed

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('imagePath');
            $table->string('title');  
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');    
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

THis is what cmd returns
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3QMc.png)
Since I cant post for another 90 minutes and I need to fix this relatively fast I will edit this post.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your namespace. Note that they are case sensitive. App vs app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the wrong namespace. Change the code to this:

```php
public function run()
{
    $product=new \App\Product([
        'imagepath' =>'https://cdn.djcity.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/14082413/launchkey-mini-elevated_0.jpg',
        'title' =>'Novation LaunchKey Mini mk2 MIDI',
        'description' =>'issa book',
        'price' =>'125'
    ]);
    $product ->save();
}
```

Comment: That definetely helped but now I am getting [this error](https://i.gyazo.com/dea85921c36c71a9a3dd769ffac2dccc.png)

Comment: Probably, you forgot to migrate. Run this command in the console: php artisan migrate

Comment: I did the dumpautoload before and then this and it says nothing to migrate

Comment: This refers to another issue. Create a new post with the migration file so we can help you as fast as possible.

Comment: I cant post for another 90 minutes so I just edites this one

Comment: Your Schema must look like this: Schema::create('products')... Notice I wrote 'products' instead of 'product'. Rollback the migration and re-run it.

Comment: Okay that helped but now I am getting Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1

Comment: Ok fixed it!! I tried to insert 350s into Price where it is integer, made a typo, thank you very much everyone who helped

Comment: Glad we helped you. You can mark the answer as solved by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace is case sensitive `\app\Product` should be `\App\Product`

What might also help is use the command `composer dumpautoload`